# SPARQL query to find all sub classes and a super class of a given class 

Tags: rdf, sparql, rdfs

I need to write a SPARQL query to find a superclass/subclasses of a given class.

For example, given http://139.91.183.30:9090/RDF/VRP/Examples/Phenomenon.rdf RDFS vocabulary file, I want to find the superclass of 'AcousticWave' (which is 'Wave').

Similarly if user enters 'Wave', I want to get all sub classes of 'Wave' (which are 'AcousticWave', 'GravityWave', 'InternalWave' and Tide').

[image]

How would I write such SPARQL query?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The predicate used in `rdfs` for state sub/super class relationships is `rdfs:subClassOf`. With that in mind you just need to write triple patterns in your SPARQL query that bind that predicate and the subject or object that you want to match --- `AcousticWave` in your case.

I hope that the following queries are self-explanatory.

for super classes ...

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX ns: <http://www.domain.com/your/namespace/>

SELECT ?superClass WHERE { ns:AcousticWave rdfs:subClassOf ?superClass . }
```

And for sub classes ...

```
SELECT ?subClass WHERE { ?subClass rdfs:subClassOf ns:Wave . }
```

If you want to retrieve the labels for every subclass of `ns:Wave` you would do something like ...

```
SELECT ?subClass ?label WHERE { 
        ?subClass rdfs:subClassOf ns:Wave . 
        ?subClass rdfs:label ?label . 
}
```

If you need the transitive closure of sub/super classes then you have two options:

1. Iterate recursively over these queries until you have collected the closure.
2. Pass your RDF data through a RDF/RDFS reasoner to forward chain all entailments and assert these in your RDF database.

Comment: Which namespace should i use for class Wave here in above file ?

Comment: It really depends on the data. I put a sample namespace because I did not know when I answer the question here.

Comment: There a SPARQL way to do transitive query using operator * or + over predicate see the [Property Path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) part from the W3C.
For all transitive sub classes of owl:thing :
`SELECT ?subClass WHERE { ?subClass rdfs:subClassOf* owl:thing .}`

It should answer : ns:Wave, ns:Tide…
See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569810/sparql-querying-transitive).