# SPARQL zick-zack pattern query

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, virtuoso, sparqlwrapper

I have an SPARQL query that mimics a zick-zack pattern like following.

```
?p1 :infector ?p.
?p2 :infector ?p1.
?p3 :infector ?p2.
?p4 :infector ?p3.
?p5 :infector ?p4
.................
```

Basically, in the pattern subject of one triple using as an object for next one. Is there any way to generalize this pattern? Therefore, I do not need to use a long list of variables (?p-?p5) in the pattern. Also, I do not know how many of such variables I need before running the query for multiple times. Hence, I can not come up with a defined set of variables. I need something generic. If you have any idea to make this query generic then please let me know. I will highly appreciate any help.

### Clarification:

I have an RDF graph like following.

```
<http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/dendrogram/experiment_id#7385/cell_id#86304/infectee_pid#446734805/iteration#0> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infector_pid> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#449563560>.

<http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/dendrogram/experiment_id#7385/cell_id#86304/infectee_pid#446734805/iteration#0> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infectee_pid> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446734805>

<http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/dendrogram/experiment_id#7385/cell_id#86304/infectee_pid#446753456/iteration#0> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infector_pid> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446734805>.

<http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/dendrogram/experiment_id#7385/cell_id#86304/infectee_pid#446753456/iteration#0> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infectee_pid> <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/person/pid#446753456>.

.......................................................................
```

Following SPARQL query can fetch existing chain mentioned above RDF graph.

```
select * from <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/> where
where { 
{
?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infector_pid> ?o1.
?s <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infectee_pid> ?o2
}

{
?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infector_pid> ?o2.
?s1 <http://ndssl.bi.vt.edu/chicago/vocab/dendrogram_infectee_pid> ?o3
}
 ..........................................................................

}
```

This chain type of query contains two parts where infectee ID from first part of the query using as an infector for second part. In my query, I have lots of parts. Is there any way to generalize it? So that insetad of using so many parts I can just use one part and get the result. BTW I need path length and intermediate node information as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPARQL Querying Transitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569810/sparql-querying-transitive)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to know path length and intermediate node information as well. Solution available in the link does not provide that information.

Comment: I see. Is this closer to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4056008/824425

Comment: Today I learned zigzag (in American English) is zickzack in some other parts of the world.  :)

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, in the pattern subject of one triple using as an object for
>   next one. Is there any way to generalize this pattern?

First, note if you consider your triple patterns in the other direction, then it's not so much of a zig-zag, but just a chain:

```
?p5 :infector ?p4 .
?p4 :infector ?p3 .
?p3 :infector ?p2 .
?p2 :infector ?p1 .
?p1 :infector ?p0 .
```

That's easy to capture with a repetition property path:

```
?p5 :infector* ?p0
```

You can reverse the direction if you want to see ?p0 appear in the text of your query first by reversing the direction of the property path:

```
?p0 ^:infector* ?p5
```

> I need to know path length and intermediate node information as well.

Since you talk the "path length", it sounds like you want a maximal path.  This makes things a little bit trickier, but you can still do this.  You can apply the approach from [Is it possible to get the position of an element in an RDF Collection in SPARQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523804/is-it-possible-to-get-the-position-of-an-element-in-an-rdf-collection-in-sparql).  To get the length of the path from ?begin to ?end, you can do something like:

```sql
select ?begin ?end (count(?mid) as ?length) {
  ?end :infector* ?mid .
  ?mid :infector* ?begin .
}
group by ?begin ?end
```

That will find the length of every :infector path.  If you only want maximal paths, you'll need to make sure that the path can't be extended in either direction from ?begin or ?end:

```sql
select ?begin ?end (count(?mid) as ?length) {
  ?end :infector* ?mid .
  ?mid :infector* ?begin .

  filter not exists { ?begin :infector ?beginEx }
  filter not exists { ?endEx :infector ?end }
}
group by ?begin ?end
```

That requires grouping over the ?mid variable, so you can't get non-aggregate information about the middle nodes at the same time that you're getting the length, but when you *don't* get the length, you can get information about the middle nodes:

```sql
select * {
  ?end :infector* ?mid .
  ?mid :infector* ?begin .

  filter not exists { ?begin :infector ?beginEx }
  filter not exists { ?endEx :infector ?end }

  #-- information about ?mid, e.g,. 
  #-- ?mid rdfs:label ?midLabel . 
}
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for. I made a new post that clarifies my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711732/sparql-chain-query). Sorry for the inconvenience. It will be a great help if you provide some feedback on my new post.

Comment: It would be better to keep this thread open and edit the question.

Comment: @S.M.ShamimulHasan I agree with AKSW;  if you have clarifications on this question, please clarify this question in preference to creating a new one.